# Make API call of one java application from another in cloud foundry?

Tags: cloud-foundry, paas

We have a requirement where we would like to call the API of one java application from another application deployed in the same cloud foundry.

Could you please tell if there is any way to access the api.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Spring Cloud Netflix project:

http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/

The service registration and discovery features of Eureka are exactly what you are looking for, and are built for use in a cloud environment.

This article contains code samples:

https://spring.io/blog/2015/01/20/microservice-registration-and-discovery-with-spring-cloud-and-netflix-s-eureka

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage [Pivotal Spring Cloud Services](https://docs.pivotal.io/spring-cloud-services/1-3/common/) in your Spring boot App. You might be using Pivotal SCS libraries.

In order to expose API to an another app, you've to enable service discovery and get registered in Eureka Server.

https://docs.pivotal.io/spring-cloud-services/1-3/common/service-registry/writing-client-applications.html#add-application-dependencies